# Adding single item to rails has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have a has_many :thorugh relationship between customers and software products they own.

```rb
# company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :company_sources
    has_many :sources, :through => :company_sources
end

# source.rb
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :company_sources
    has_many :companies, :through => :company_sources
end

# company_source.rb
class CompanySource < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :source
end
```

The controllers are the default `rails g scaffold <name>` files

I need a selection form on the company edit page that will allow the addition of a single source to the company_source table.

The closest I can get is using the selection form helper, however that will overwrite the previous addition when I go to add a new item.

I've been playing with this for quite a few hours now and I can't seem to get the form/routes/controller right.

This is the form I'm playing with at the time of writing

```
<table>
  <% @company.sources.each do |source| %>
    <tr><%= source.name %></tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
      <%= form_for @company do |f| %>
        <td>
          <%= select("source", "id", Source.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}, { include_blank: true })%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= f.submit "Add Source" %>
        </td>
      <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Full controller (again, at time of writing)

```html
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /companies
  # GET /companies.json
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  # GET /companies/1
  # GET /companies/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /companies/new
  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  # GET /companies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /companies
  # POST /companies.json
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /companies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /companies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update(company_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      if (params[:source_id])
        @company.source << Source.find(params[:source_id])
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /companies/1
  # DELETE /companies/1.json
  def destroy
    @company.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to companies_url, notice: 'Company was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :description, :source_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: I understand I can use the `<<` operator to add a single item, but I can't seem to get the source_id back to the controller.

Comment: can you post you form code?

Comment: @inye I've posted it above, however I've been trying about every example I can find online, so that's just the most recent.

Comment: Do you use [fields_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)? Also you can use [gem cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Comment: what's the rendered html? probably you're not assigning correctly the ID/name to the select tag hence the check for the param is not returning true. Try `f.select(:source_id, options_for_select(Source.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}), { include_blank: true })`

Answer (score 0):

In the `update` action, I propose not doing `@company.update`, and instead doing:

```
company_source = CompanySource.create!(company: @company, source: Source.find(source_id)
```

(Warning: There might be errors in the code, which you should be able to correct fairly easily)

So, the `update` action would look like:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    company_source = CompanySource.new(company: @company, source_id: params[:source_id])

    if company_source.save
      format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @company }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: company_source.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Although this shifts the perspective to that of the `CompanySource` despite being inside the `CompaniesController`, what you are really wanting to do is create a new `CompanySource`. I think this is the most straightforward way of looking at it.

This will ensure correct updates of the `Compnay`-`Source` relationship.